# Center icon in a transparent square for SVG export

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I have a file with many art boards within, each has an icon. I've exported all the icons in to there own .ai file and now I want them all to be exported as SVG's centered in a square so they are all uniform when I add them to a web project. I've tried changing the art board on each to 500px by 500px but this doesn't work.. I've tried adding a invisible sqaure and exporting the SVG but this doesn't work..

How do you export a SVG from illustrator which is simply 500px by 500px with an icon in the center?

Sorry I'm quite new to Illustrator.

Comment: You should be using CSS to arrange your SVG graphics on the web. See tutorial on CSS-Tricks: [Using SVG](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/)

Comment: Artboards are *never* part of an SVG file form Illustrator and a non-visible object won't be included because it would be superfluous code in the SVG file. As @AndrewH points out, you should just create divs and position the SVG files within the div using CSS.

Comment: @Scott what happens when you export the SVG and you check the "Use Artboards" box? Is that info only relevant when opening the file back in Illustrator?

Comment: @AndrewH it uses artboards to designate separate files but the dimensions of the artboard are never saved within the SVG file. SVG files don't have an "artboard" or "canvas" area. Illustrator adds one because Illustrator MUST have one. Related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28171/importing-svg-into-illustrator-with-proper-viewbox-size  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39505/illustrator-exporting-svg-viewbox-doesnt-match-artboard-size/39535#39535 http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15401/change-viewbox-attribute-in-svg-exported-by-illustrator

Comment: I don't know why the SVG viewbox attribute is not seen or created by Illustrator, I merely know it's not.